# MySQL Query using data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like so:

```
Table 1: tracks
id  | artist     | track
---------------------------------------
1     Tom Smith    This Time is Right Time
2     Tom Smith    Oh Yes
3     John Doe     Every Time I See You

Table 2: festival_bands
id  | fest_title | fest_artist
---------------------------------------
1     Hoe Down Fest 2019    John Doe
2     Copperland Fest       Tom Smith
3     Copperland Fest       Reggie Wisk
4     Copperland Fest       Tom Smith
5     Copperland Fest       John Doe
6     Bluegrass Memories    John Doe
```

I need to show only ONE "track" from table 1 for each festival listing from Table 2 like so:
Results:

```
Copperland Festival:
-----------------------
Tom Smith    This Time is Right Time
John Doe     Every Time I See You
```

In layman's terms, the logic would be along the lines of:
Get only one track from TABLE 1 where artist equals (or matches) fest_artist from TABLE 2

I referenced a similar question which advised something in the direction of:
`$sql="select * from tracks WHERE (artist) in (select fest_artist from festival_bands group by name)"` but with no luck.

Comment: Is there any logic at all regarding which track gets selected?  Or, do you really just want a random selection?

Comment: Good question - if I was to use one, it would be based on most popular... each track has a counter so I would use "WHERE counter is greatest"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to get a random track for the artist:

```
select fb.*,
       (select t.track
        from tracks t
        where t.artist = fb.fest_artist
        order by t.counter desc
       ) as most_popular_track
from festival_bands fb;
```

Comment: Just for my understanding, where does the "fb." and "t." originate from and what does it actually do?

Comment: @Davo . . . Those are table aliases and they are an important part of the SQL language.